# Is this a valid model for such a view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Is it correct a model?

```
public class NewForm
{
    public string[] Field { get; set; }
    public bool[] Check { get; set; }
}
```

for such a VIEW:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Field)
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Field)
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Field)

@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Check)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Check)
```

Or is there a better way to create fields of the same name?
In Controller displays only the first value. But i need all

```
        [HttpPost]

    public ActionResult Edit(NewForm model)
    {
        Response.Write(model.Field);
        Response.Write(model.Check);
    }
```

Fields may be an indefinite number due to the fact that by clicking on the button JavaScript adds a new field of the same name with the same name

Comment: What is your expected behavior?

Comment: for questions like "Is this correct"  please use https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

It *sounds* like you want to submit multiple instances of your `model` back to the controller.

You could do something like this. My example will submit 10 instances of `Field` back to your controller.

**View:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
    @for(int i = 0; i<10; i++) 
    {
        <div>@Html.TextBox("items[" + i + "].Field", "", new { id = "items[" + i + "].Field", placeholder = "Enter Text..." })</div>
        @Html.Hidden("items.Index", i)
    }
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

**Class:**

```
public class MyClass 
{
    public string Field {get;set;}
}
```

**Controller Method:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ActionName(List<MyClass> items)
{
   //...do stuff
}
```

Obviously you could also add your checkbox into the model and form too in order to submit many of those.

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to be the same name for the fields, each field has proper name

```
public class NewForm
{
    public string FirstField { get; set; }
    public string Field { get; set; }
    public bool Check { get; set; }
}
```

VIEW

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.FirstField)
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Field)

@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Check)
```

ee

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(NewForm model)
{
    Response.Write(model.FirstField);
    Response.Write(model.Field);
    Response.Write(model.Check);
}
```

Comment: How can I receive data on the controller if there are several identical name of fields, is the  array?

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't. In the model you defined, you have created two different arrays: The first property `Field` is an array of strings and the second property `Check` an array of bools. putting the `[]` after a type indicates an array.

If you have an unknown number of what I'll call "mini forms" and the number of these is decided by the user via the UI, then you should create a view model to represent this mini form, and a container view model to house it and any other properties your view will need.

For example:

```
public class MiniFormViewModel
{
    public string MyInput { get; set; }
    public bool MyCheck { get; set; }
}
```

then in your container view model:

```
public class ContainerViewModel
{ 
    public IEnumerable<MiniFormViewModel> MiniForms { get; set; } 
    //Any other properties you need on the view that will occur a single time 
}
```

Now, in the JS you'll need to add some manipulation in order to do this:

```
function getViewModel() {
    //You'll have to decide how you want to get the values of the mini form's fields. Perhaps you might even have a function to supply these values. Up to you.
    return {
        MiniForms: [{
                MyInput: '', //value from the first "mini form' string field
                Mycheck: false //value from the first "mini-form" bool field
            },
            {
                MyInput: '', //value from the second"mini form' string field
                Mycheck: false //value from the second"mini-form" bool field
            }      
        ]
    }
}
```

Then you'll need to post this back to the server. I'll demonstrate how to do this via the built in JS Fetch function:

```
        fetch(yourUrlForTheControllerAction,
            {
                method: 'post',
                body: JSON.stringify(getViewModel()),
                headers: {
                    'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
                }
            })
```

And then blammo, you should be good to go. I excluded the part of dynamically adding the mini form fields because it sounds like you have a solution for that already.

Comment: There may be an indefinite number of fields due to the fact that by clicking on the button JavaScript adds a new field of the same with the same name

Comment: ahh I see. Then you would have to do some manipulation in the JS to create an array of strings and bool, JSON.stringify that, and post that back to the model. To my knowledge there is no Razor helper to do what you describe.

Comment: @vamp123 I made edits to my original answer. See if that is a viable solution for you! Let me know if there is something else I can provide to assist you.